# sticky sidebar in flexbox design

Tags: css, flexbox

How to make the sidebars in the holy grail layout made with flexbox be made sticky? ie. the aside and nav portion of the html should stop scrolling down further when the last element has reached. I tried multiple ways but achieved little success.

HTML:

```
<body>
     <header>header</header>
     <div id='main'>
        <article>This area has lot of content </article>`
        <nav> This nav should not scroll</nav>
        <aside>This aside too</div></aside>
     </div>
     <footer>footer</footer>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
   /*font: 24px Helvetica;*/
   background: #999999;
  }

  #main {
   min-height: 800px;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display:         flex;
   -webkit-flex-flow: row;
           flex-flow: row;
   }

  #main > article {
   margin: 4px;
   padding: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #cccc33;
   border-radius: 7pt;
   background: #dddd88;
   -webkit-flex: 3 1 60%;
           flex: 3 1 60%;
   -webkit-order: 2;
           order: 2;
   }

  #main > nav {
   margin: 4px;
   padding: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #8888bb;
   border-radius: 7pt;
   background: #ccccff;
   -webkit-flex: 1 6 20%;
           flex: 1 6 20%;
   -webkit-order: 1;
           order: 1;
   }

  #main > aside {
   margin: 4px;
   padding: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #8888bb;
   border-radius: 7pt;
   background: #ccccff;
   -webkit-flex: 1 6 20%;
           flex: 1 6 20%;
   -webkit-order: 3;
           order: 3;
   }

  header, footer {
   display: block;
   margin: 4px;
   padding: 5px;
   min-height: 100px;
   border: 1px solid #eebb55;
   border-radius: 7pt;
   background: #ffeebb;
   }
```

Comment: I'm also trying to figure this out! Here is an up to date CodePen with an example: http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/XMXRqo

Comment: I added a bounty... but I doubt there is any reliable way to do this.

Comment: @sheriffderek can you explain the issue a little better? I'm having difficulties following OP's description.

Comment: This sounds like it would need to be done with js. Are you open to that?

Comment: yes can you please give some more clear requirements so that we can solve it

Comment: @sheriffdereki answered using your codepen..

Comment: @SergChernata - look at the CodePen. It already has JS, so to answer your question - yes - I am open to using JS.

Comment: The problem is that once the 'sidebar' goes 'fixed' - you have to specify an explicit width. Also, you have to deal with the fact that the sidebar is now out of the flow, so the primary 'column' needs to be grow: 0 etc. It's just not really wonderful - so if you have a better way to do ALL of those things, that would be how to answer this questions.

Comment: @sheriffderek I posted a solution, let me know if I understood you correctly.

Comment: It's not safe to assume that, because @sheriffderek will accept a jQuery solution, OP would also accept a jQuery solution. If sheriffderek wants to change the scope of the question, he should create his own question, per this discussion on Meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314764/what-do-you-do-when-a-question-gets-hijacked-for-a-bounty

Comment: It doesn't help that in your HTML you've closed your `#main` prematurely.

Comment: What I took from the question (likely based on my personal experience) is that when you use js to 'fix' the 'sidebar,' it has to break out of flexbox world. Can the standard Sticky footer be done while it retains it's flexbox layout.  Here's the pen without a bandaid. http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/XMXRqo?editors=0110  I don't even know why the widgets stay on their horizontal axis in the first place... but they lose their shape.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the new CSS3 `position: sticky` on the `nav` and `aside` elements?

The disadvantage to this approach is that it's not supported by Internet Explorer, but it does require zero Javascript.

I made that change here:

```css
body {
   /*font: 24px Helvetica;*/
   background: #999999;
  }

  #main {
  position: relative;
   min-height: 800px;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display:         flex;
   -webkit-flex-flow: row;
           flex-flow: row;
   }

  #main > article {
   margin: 4px;
   padding: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #cccc33;
   border-radius: 7pt;
   background: #dddd88;
   -webkit-flex: 3 1 60%;
           flex: 3 1 60%;
   -webkit-order: 2;
           order: 2;
   }

  #main > nav {
  
   margin: 4px;
   padding: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #8888bb;
   border-radius: 7pt;
   background: #ccccff;
   -webkit-flex: 1 6 20%;
           flex: 1 6 20%;
   -webkit-order: 1;
           order: 1;
   }

  #main > aside {
   margin: 4px;
   padding: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #8888bb;
   border-radius: 7pt;
   background: #ccccff;
   -webkit-flex: 1 6 20%;
           flex: 1 6 20%;
   -webkit-order: 3;
           order: 3;
   }

#main > nav, #main > aside {
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
}

  header, footer {
   display: block;
   margin: 4px;
   padding: 5px;
   min-height: 100px;
   border: 1px solid #eebb55;
   border-radius: 7pt;
   background: #ffeebb;
   }
```

```html
<body>
     <header>header</header>
     <div id='main'>
        <article>This area has lot of content </article>`
        <nav> This nav should not scroll</nav>
        <aside>This aside too</div></aside>
     </div>
     <footer>footer</footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I actually understood what you're trying to achieve, this should be along the lines of what you're looking for. The meat of the solution lies in defining three states or three conditions for positioning the element. In order of appearance:

1. If we've scrolled past the beginning of sidebar but haven't reached the end of sidebar just yet. Minus the height of the menu itself.
2. If we've scrolled past the end of sidebar minus the height of it's menu.
3. If the page scroll value is less than the beginning point of the sidebar. Ie, the natural state of the menu, before we scroll.

---

```
if(currentScrollPosition >= sidebarPosition && currentScrollPosition <= threshold)
{
     $widget.css({top: 10, position:'fixed'});
}
else if(currentScrollPosition >= threshold)
{
    $widget.css({top: threshold, position:'absolute'});
}
else if(currentScrollPosition <= sidebarPosition)
{
    $widget.css({top: 'auto', position:'static'});
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jByPEJ

Comment: This is the same idea we are already working with, but in our case, we are adding and removing a class vs explicitly setting the style with JS. http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/XMXRqo

Comment: Right, but yours doesn't work if the nav menu ever reaches the footer.

Comment: Yeah. That's true, but that's not really the 'sticky' part, is it?

Comment: Can you explain it better? I honestly thought this was it.

Comment: I can't really explain it better. There is an example trying to show the problem, but it's a strange group of problems... Can the sidebar be fixed to the top while still being fluid in width? How does it know where to live spacially? I think the true answer is - don't ever make sticky sidebars... but I thought I'd toss 200 at it and see what happened.

Comment: @sheriffderek check my pen again, I think I see what the problem is, it might be closer to what you're looking for now.

Comment: Drag the screen small - and then wide again to see some interesting things happen.

Comment: @sheriffderek I did, did you revisit my pen? I added setSize method.

Comment: Yes. I revisited the pen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137684/discussion-between-serg-chernata-and-sheriffderek).

Answer (score 0):

Make Sidebar Sticky  using javscript and css with easy Steps here.

```js
$(function(){

var stickySidebar = $('.sticky');

if (stickySidebar.length > 0) { 
  var stickyHeight = stickySidebar.height(),
      sidebarTop = stickySidebar.offset().top;
}

// on scroll move the sidebar
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if (stickySidebar.length > 0) { 
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            
    if (sidebarTop < scrollTop) {
      stickySidebar.css('top', scrollTop - sidebarTop);

      // stop the sticky sidebar at the footer to avoid overlapping
      var sidebarBottom = stickySidebar.offset().top + stickyHeight,
          stickyStop = $('.main-content').offset().top + $('.main-content').height();
      if (stickyStop < sidebarBottom) {
        var stopPosition = $('.main-content').height() - stickyHeight;
        stickySidebar.css('top', stopPosition);
      }
    }
    else {
      stickySidebar.css('top', '0');
    } 
  }
});

$(window).resize(function () {
  if (stickySidebar.length > 0) { 
    stickyHeight = stickySidebar.height();
  }
}); });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 25px;
  background-color: #361039;
  color: #E2E0DE;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  display: block;
  background-color: #121325;
  font-size: 24px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 2%;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

aside {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: #5C255A;
}

.sticky {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

footer {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  background-color: #121325;
  font-size: 24px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 2%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>This is a header</header>

<section class="main-content">
  <article>
    <h1>This is Paragraph</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis quis nibh gravida, gravida nisl ac, imperdiet sem. Fusce quis malesuada magna. Vivamus dignissim gravida tellus sed pulvinar. Morbi eleifend dolor vel velit viverra aliquam. In pharetra felis non leo congue, id iaculis dui laoreet. Pellentesque accumsan ligula sed nisl eleifend consequat. Proin at orci purus. Praesent dignissim at odio nec fringilla. Nulla lacinia ultricies auctor. Mauris vel diam nunc. Ut lorem arcu, interdum id tortor a, tincidunt vestibulum eros. Vivamus sit amet mattis turpis. Nullam auctor ut velit nec adipiscing. Morbi et vehicula diam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis quis nibh gravida, gravida nisl ac, imperdiet sem. Fusce quis malesuada magna. Vivamus dignissim gravida tellus sed pulvinar. Morbi eleifend dolor vel velit viverra aliquam. In pharetra felis non leo congue, id iaculis dui laoreet. Pellentesque accumsan ligula sed nisl eleifend consequat. Proin at orci purus. Praesent dignissim at odio nec fringilla. Nulla lacinia ultricies auctor. Mauris vel diam nunc. Ut lorem arcu, interdum id tortor a, tincidunt vestibulum eros. Vivamus sit amet mattis turpis. Nullam auctor ut velit nec adipiscing. Morbi et vehicula diam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis quis nibh gravida, gravida nisl ac, imperdiet sem. Fusce quis malesuada magna. Vivamus dignissim gravida tellus sed pulvinar. Morbi eleifend dolor vel velit viverra aliquam. In pharetra felis non leo congue, id iaculis dui laoreet. Pellentesque accumsan ligula sed nisl eleifend consequat. Proin at orci purus. Praesent dignissim at odio nec fringilla. Nulla lacinia ultricies auctor. Mauris vel diam nunc. Ut lorem arcu, interdum id tortor a, tincidunt vestibulum eros. Vivamus sit amet mattis turpis. Nullam auctor ut velit nec adipiscing. Morbi et vehicula diam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis quis nibh gravida, gravida nisl ac, imperdiet sem. Fusce quis malesuada magna. Vivamus dignissim gravida tellus sed pulvinar. Morbi eleifend dolor vel velit viverra aliquam. In pharetra felis non leo congue, id iaculis dui laoreet. Pellentesque accumsan ligula sed nisl eleifend consequat. Proin at orci purus. Praesent dignissim at odio nec fringilla. Nulla lacinia ultricies auctor. Mauris vel diam nunc. Ut lorem arcu, interdum id tortor a, tincidunt vestibulum eros. Vivamus sit amet mattis turpis. Nullam auctor ut velit nec adipiscing. Morbi et vehicula diam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis quis nibh gravida, gravida nisl ac, imperdiet sem. Fusce quis malesuada magna. Vivamus dignissim gravida tellus sed pulvinar. Morbi eleifend dolor vel velit viverra aliquam. In pharetra felis non leo congue, id iaculis dui laoreet. Pellentesque accumsan ligula sed nisl eleifend consequat. Proin at orci purus. Praesent dignissim at odio nec fringilla. Nulla lacinia ultricies auctor. Mauris vel diam nunc. Ut lorem arcu, interdum id tortor a, tincidunt vestibulum eros. Vivamus sit amet mattis turpis. Nullam auctor ut velit nec adipiscing. Morbi et vehicula diam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis quis nibh gravida, gravida nisl ac, imperdiet sem. Fusce quis malesuada magna. Vivamus dignissim gravida tellus sed pulvinar. Morbi eleifend dolor vel velit viverra aliquam. In pharetra felis non leo congue, id iaculis dui laoreet. Pellentesque accumsan ligula sed nisl eleifend consequat. Proin at orci purus. Praesent dignissim at odio nec fringilla. Nulla lacinia ultricies auctor. Mauris vel diam nunc. Ut lorem arcu, interdum id tortor a, tincidunt vestibulum eros. Vivamus sit amet mattis turpis. Nullam auctor ut velit nec adipiscing. Morbi et vehicula diam.</p>
  </article>
</section>

<aside class="sticky">
  <h1>This is a sticky sidebar</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <p>Duis quis nibh gravida, gravida nisl ac, imperdiet sem. Fusce quis malesuada magna.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</aside>

<footer>This is a footer</footer>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have taken up the code from code pen and rewritten the **JS code**  with some logic made with sidebar as required.Hope it is helpful :)

```js
var stickArea = $('aside ul');
var footArea = $('footer');
margin = 10;
offtop = stickArea.offset().top - margin;
offbtm = footArea.offset().top - (margin * 3 + stickArea.height());

$(window).scroll(function() {
  topScr = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (topScr > offtop && stickArea.hasClass('natural')) {
    stickArea.removeClass('natural').addClass('fixed').css('top', margin);
  }
  if (offtop > topScr && stickArea.hasClass('fixed')) {
    stickArea.removeClass('fixed').addClass('natural').css('top', 'auto');
  }
  if (topScr > offbtm && stickArea.hasClass('fixed')) {
    stickArea.removeClass('fixed').addClass('bottom').css('top', offbtm);
  }
  if (offbtm > topScr && stickArea.hasClass('bottom')) {
    stickArea.removeClass('bottom').addClass('fixed').css('top', margin);
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.master {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.master .inner-w {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 960px;
  flex-basis: 960px;
}

.master main {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .master main {
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}

.master .content {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 70%;
  flex-basis: 70%;
  min-height: 2000px;
}

.master aside {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 350px;
  flex-basis: 350px;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex-positive: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.master aside .widget-list {
  width: 330px;
}

body.sticky-sidebar .master aside .widget-list {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #add8e6;
  padding: 10px;
}

.master {
  background: #90ee90;
}

.master .inner-w {
  padding: 10px;
}

.master header,
.master .content,
.master aside,
.master footer {
  padding: 10px;
}

.master header {
  background: #ffc0cb;
  min-height: 120px;
}

.master .content {
  background: #f5deb3;
}

.master aside {
  background: #ffd700;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.master aside .widget-list {
  background: #d3d3d3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.master aside .widget-list .widget {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 10px;
}

.master aside .widget-list .widget:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.master footer {
  background: #808080;
  min-height: 500px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}


/** additional Css For Sidebar Logic **/

.master aside .widget-list.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}

.master aside .widget-list.bottom {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='master'>
  <div class='inner-w'>

    <header>
      <h1>Attempts at a sticky sidebar for squishy and more-complex flex-box layouts - sorta ~ eh?</h1>
    </header>

    <main>
      <div class='content'>
        content
      </div>

      <aside class="">
        <ul class='widget-list natural'>
          <li class='widget'>
            widget 1
          </li>
          <li class='widget'>
            widget 2
          </li>
          <li class='widget'>
            widget 3
          </li>


        </ul>
      </aside>
    </main>

    <footer>
      footer
    </footer>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should explain what your code does differently than the supplied code.